# What is the mass and power consumption of the COLBERT treadmill?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, nasa, health

What do you  think is the mass and power consumption of the [COLBERT treadmill](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/765.html)? Sources are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maintenance was done on the treadmill in March: http://spaceref.com/international-space-station/nasa-iss-weekly-space-to-ground-report---march-7-2018.html.

Answer (score 3):

The most detailed public info on the treadmill I've seen is in the CHeCs Catalog, available [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110022379.pdf).

Description of the T2 treadmill (you'll see that the word COLBERT doesn't appear in this document...) starts on pdf page 104.

It doesn't give power load for the system explicitly, but paragraph 2.8.2.4 shows that there is a 120 volt DC, 25 amp feed to the system, and gives these component maximum power loads:

- AAA Fan, max 175 watts
- Display, max 70 watts
- Treadmill motor, max 800 watts
- SLS, max 400 watts  (when this document was written, the SLS had not
  been provided yet)
- UEIPAC - max 15 watts

[image]

The mass is not given in this document but [called2voyage](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/58/called2voyage) kindly pointed out that it's given as 2200 pounds at this [page](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/behindscenes/colbert_feature.html).

Acronymology:

- AAA - Avionics Air Assembly
- ISPR - International Standard Payload Rack
- SLS - Subject Loading System
- SSPCM -Solid State Power Control Module
- UEIPAC - United Electronic Industries Programmable Automation Controller